# C# unit test environment different from Application

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a class that I'll describe as a "black box". Among another things, it makes a TCP/IP connection to a server.  I do not have the source code to this black box.

The class works fine when it is used from within a console or gui application.  The class does not function when it is used inside of a Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestMethod.  (It throws an unhelpful "unknown error" exception.)

What is the nature of Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestMethod and why does it not give a class the "same environment" as an application? What about the "environment" is different? Perhaps some static initialization is not performed.  Perhaps some "singletons" are not initialized.  Perhaps there is no "Main" at the top of the call stack and my black box can reflect on that?

Comment: One thing I know is that `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` is null because the entry point is unmanaged.

Comment: If you're not testing the black box (and you don't have the source, so there'd be no point?), could you just mock it out?

Comment: @Blorgbeard I guess he's making some integration or acceptance tests. Else he would not be using it like that.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I am testing a wrapper around the black box.  I wrote the wrapper.  The test fails because the black box "senses" that it is not being executed from within a proper application.  I'd love to understand what the black box could be "sensing" to determine that there is no proper application running.

Comment: Most likely a configuration setting that was not set up in the test environment. You should start by making sure the "black box"'s configuration have been set up properly in the test project